# Finding the minimum sum within an array of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to find the minimum sum of consecutive numbers of the number of lines within an excel sheet of ca. 10.000 rows.

```
1 200
2 -100
3 -300
4 100
5 100
6 100
```

This should give -400 and 2 rows (this can be in another formula of course).

```
1 0
2 100
3 -100
4 -100
5 -100
6 100
7 -100
8 100
```

This should give -300 and 3 rows etc.

Thanks!

Comment: So what exactly have you tried?

Comment: This is a data of roughly 20 years or so. It has every single date in it. What I did is, select 30, 60, 90, 120 days sums it get the minimum with an array formula. That only gives me worst streak in respective range. And this only gives the data with trial and error. I might have to try until i reach 3600 days for example.

Comment: That's not what you've tried. Show us the code/formulas you have tried. SO can't write code for you.

Comment: There is an obvious O(n^2) solution that would be easy to code, but with 10,000 rows execution might crawl

Comment: First I sum the data by every 10 days. Then I run {=MIN(G2:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G))+G3:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G)+1)+G4:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G)+2)+G5:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G)+3)+G6:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G)+4)+G7:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G)+5)+G8:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G)+6)+G9:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G)+7)+G10:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G)+8)+G11:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G)+9)+G12:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G)+10)+G13:INDIRECT("G"&COUNTA(G:G)+11))}

Comment: If it were me, I would make a second "helper" column with a formula like `=SUM(A1:A$1)`, and copy it down.  Then use the "Min" function on the helper column.

Comment: This is a variation of the maximum subarray problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem. You could get the complexity down to O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Arrays this process took 3-4 seconds on 10,000 lines:

```
Sub minarr()

Dim i&, j&
Dim rngArr() As Variant
Dim sum As Double
Dim frstrw As Long
Dim lstrw As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Minout As Double

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet28") 'Change to your sheet

'Change column A to the column of your numbers in the next two lines.
lastrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
rngArr = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Value

For i = 1 To lastrow
    sum = rngArr(i, 1)
    For j = i + 1 To lastrow
        sum = sum + rngArr(j, 1)
        If sum < Minout Then
            Minout = sum
            frstrw = i
            lstrw = j
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Debug.Print Minout
Debug.Print frstrw
Debug.Print lstrw

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This made my day and works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a debugged `O(n)` solution. It is virtually instantaneous with 10,000 items. The algorithm is a variation of Kadane's algorithm for solving the [maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) (which @rajah9 points out as being a close match to this problem):

```
Function MinSum(Target As Range) As Variant
    'Target is a 1-dimensional range of numbers
    'Returns a variant array containing
    '0) The minimum sum of consecutive numbers in R
    '1) The starting index of the sum
    '2) The ending index of the sum

    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim A As Variant 'A(i,1) = value of best subsequence ending at i, A(i,2) is corresponding start value
    Dim v As Variant 'currently scanned value
    Dim minS As Variant 'the min sum
    Dim minAt As Variant 'where it occurs in A

    With Target
        'initialize
        n = .Cells.Count
        ReDim A(1 To n, 1 To 2)
        v = .Cells(1)
        minS = v
        minAt = 1
        A(1, 1) = v
        A(1, 2) = 1

        'main loop
        For i = 2 To n
            v = .Cells(i)
            'the best sequence ending at i extends previous one if previous one is negative:
            If A(i - 1, 1) < 0 Then
                A(i, 1) = A(i - 1, 1) + v
                A(i, 2) = A(i - 1, 2) 'extend current subsequence
            Else 'start new subsequence
                A(i, 1) = v
                A(i, 2) = i
            End If
            'see if we have a new min:
            If A(i, 1) < minS Then
                minS = A(i, 1)
                minAt = i
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    MinSum = Array(minS, A(minAt, 2), minAt)
End Function
```

It returns an array which gives both the minimal sum and two indices, start and end of the sum in the array. It can be used as an array formula:

[image]

In the above screenshot, I have `=RANDBETWEEN(-100,100)` in cells A1:A10000 and then in cells C1:E1 I have `{=MinSum(A1:A10000)}` (Ctrl+Shift+Enter to accept as an array formula). Both the computation of the 10,000 random numbers and the determination of the minsum takes less than half a second.

Comment: I am getting a different answer between yours and mine.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Could you try mine on your data set and see if you also get different answers?

Comment: @ScottCraner Well -- I might have a bug then. My code worked with OP's test cases, but I may have missed some subtleties. Unfortunately, I'll have to wait until after work to devote more time on it.

Comment: @ScottCraner As I suspected, the bug was in my code rather than your code. With the debugged code I now get complete agreement with your code for random examples with 10,000 numbers. Thank you for bringing the bug to my attention.

Comment: Saw that and already up voted. Glad you were able to find the bug.  If it works better for the OP I would hope that the correct answer would be changed.

Comment: Thank you very much this one works as well! Very much appreciated. I am just keeping the first one as correct answer the sole reason being I am a noob when it comes to Vba coding and I can understand the first code a little better. Again thanks so much.

Comment: @user6156436 No problem -- I can understand Scott's code a little better than my own and used his code as a benchmark for debugging my own. The first good working answer is fully deserving of being accepted.